# Yet Another "Comparison method violates its general contract"

Tags: java, comparator

I have read all the other answers related to this and it looks to me like the code should work, alas, that is not the case.

```
protected static class SpecialComparator implements Comparator<SpecialDTO>
{

    @Override
    public int compare( SpecialDTO sp1, SpecialDTO sp2 )
    {
        if( !sp1.isTypeA() || !sp2.isTypeA() )
            return sp1.isTypeA().compareTo( sp2.isTypeA() );

        SpecialNestedADTO spn1 = sp1.getNestedA();
        SpecialNestedADTO spn2 = sp2.getNestedA();

        return Comparator
            .comparing( SpecialNestedADTO::getId )
            .thenComparing( SpecialNestedADTO::getReps )
            .compare( spn1, spn2 );
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this would throw an IllegalArgumentException?

It's worth mentioning that if they SpecialDTO is not TypeA then we cannot getNestedA() so the rest of the comparator should be skipped. That's why we have the if statement at the start.

Comment: Your `if` looks suspicious regarding transitivity. Consider two `sp` that are `A` and one that is not.

Comment: can you show how are you using this ?

Comment: @mehdimaick This is being called using Collections.sort( specials, new SpecialComparator() );

Comment: @chrylis I've added a test with this exact scenario but if A-B>0 and B-C>0 then A-C>0 ... I can't create a test that causes it to fail. Any ideas how to with your suggestion?

Comment: What type is `reps`?

Comment: I think @chrylis is right. I would expect that if-statement to be more like "if sp1.isTypeA() && sp2.isTypeA()".

Comment: @chrylis Integer

Comment: @onnoweb how would we handle the case where one of the two is not TypeA then?

Comment: I assume that `isTypeA()` returns `Boolean`. If so, then all non-TypeA objects are considered equal to each other and are less than all TypeA objects. Is that what you intended? (That’s not obviously wrong on its face.)

Comment: @StuartMarks That's correct, in this particular case we are prioritising TypeA objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out our customer simply hadn't upgraded the product in quite some time which means they were running on an old version of the comparator which did break the general contract.

Looks like the comparator is solid after all.